# Modal toggled in other modal - can't scroll modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I created a modal and inside the modal I created a button to open the second modal and close the first but the problem is that the scrollbar doesn't work for the second modal but works for page.

How could I fix this?

```
code in fiddle:
```

[link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Samuell/aghbw1d4/1/)

Comment: Please you create a fiddle. Or post your code.

Comment: I have answered your question. Tell me if it is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you shouldn't use `data-toggle="modal"` or `data-dismiss="modal"` (as there's no guarantee that the hiding and the showing will happen in the right order) and instead do the showing and hiding yourself. Example:

---

```
<button type="button" id="modal-2-btn">open modal 2 »</button>
```

---

```
$('#modal-2-btn').on('click', function () {
  $('#modal-trainertype').one('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#modal-food').modal('show');
  }).modal('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aghbw1d4/2/)

Add CSS:

```
#modal-food{
    overflow:auto
}
```